# Execute 2 dynamic SQL Server stored procedures with parameters and combine results with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vba, stored-procedures

Is it possible to `UNION ALL` 2 dynamic stored procedures with parameters?

I have seen answers for combining 2 dynamic stored procedures without parameters but cannot find the syntax where there are parameters to pass-through.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SLACTIVITY_SP]
   @ORGCODE AS VARCHAR(6),
   @COMPANYID AS VARCHAR(6)
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @SQLRESULT NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @SQL1 = N'SELECT * 
                  FROM TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '
                  WHERE TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '.Column1 = 1 
                    AND TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '.Column2 = @COMPANYID;';

    SET @SQL2 = N'SELECT * 
                  FROM TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '
                  WHERE TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '.Column1 = 0 
                    AND TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '.Column2 = @COMPANYID;';

--usually I write this for a single dynamic SP with parameters
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL1, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6),@COMPANYID AS VARCHAR(6)', @ORGCODE, @COMPANYID;
```

But I am not sure how to create one EXEC with parameters.

Would it be something like this?

```
SET @SQLRESULT + @SQL1 + 'UNION ALL ' + @SQL2
EXEC @SQLRESULT, N'ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @COMPANYID AS VARCHAR(6)', @ORGCODE, @COMPANYID;
```

I also tried one query with the UNION ALL inside a single stored procedure. This works if the procedure is not dynamic. But as soon as I make it dynamic all kinds of strange error messages appear.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
SET @SQL1 = N'SELECT * 
              FROM TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '
              WHERE TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '.Column1 IN (0, 1) 
              AND TABLE' + @ORGCODE + '.Column2 = @COMPANYID;';
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify that my first query is a `SUM` query and the second one is **not** a `SUM` query so I need to split them up as separate queries

Comment: @cocojay You need to make sure that both queries have the same number and type of columns.